# Syntax highlighting in parallel folders

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-c

My syntax highlighting does not work for my C-project, if I use folders in parallel. Consider this file tree:

```
project
├── include
│   ├── main.h
│   ├── file1.h
│   └── file2.h
└── src
    ├── main.c
    ├── file1.c
    └── file2.c
```

My current dir is `./project`, and I open `file1.c` like this: `$vim src/file1.c`.
I have #define's in `file2.h`, which I include in `file1.c`.

And here is my problem: those #define's or functions I call, are not highlighted. It works fine, if the header files are either in same directory or a directory below.

How can I tell Vim to consider the header files of the folder in parallel for syntax highlighting?

Comment: I'm talking about user defines/functions/enums etc. If I use a define/function from a "parallel" header file, the syntax highlighting does not check this. This means, that in my .c file, where I call functions from other header files, are not highlighted. They are just highlighted as plain text. The syntax highligther is not aware, that those defines/functions exist and therefore does not know how to highlight them. All other highlighting works, just not those of "parallel" included files.

Comment: The syntax highlighter, key phrase being _syntax_, isn't that smart. It just matches patterns. If they're not getting highlighted then they don't match expected syntax. What is the filetype in the C files? You could post a code sample with some of the working and non-working text, too.

Comment: `:echo $ft` returns `c` for the .h and .c files. include/file2.h: `#define TEST` -> src/file1.c `#ifdef TEST` -> TEST is not highlighted as a defined value in the .c file; Working example: file2.c: void my_func(void); -> file1.c: my_func(); -> this is properly highlighted. Variables/Functions, that are in the same directory or lower do get highlighted, but not the variables/functions in parallel folders.

Comment: Great but please add it to your question. Comments sometimes get lost.

Comment: It says exactly that in the question

Comment: @BLayer Thank you for your help. I could finally fix it after way too much time :| Apparently, something was wrong with my tags and types_c.taghl files. I deleted them and regenerated the tags und then it worked... Urgh. Thank you

Comment: Oh, were you talking about tags/links...where you can jump to the other file? That's a little different than the syntax highlighting I was focusing on. Anyways, glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: The tags worked, I could jump to other files. Probably it was just the types_c.taglhl file

Comment: My point is that most people when they hear "syntax highlighting" will likely think of the self-contained, file-type-specific syntax kind of highlighting as opposed to supplemental highlighting added as part of tagging and/or by a plugin. I know now that that's what you were getting at but noting explicitly the association with "tags" or "ctags" if you need to ask a question about it in the future will help a lot to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Thank you, I will. Honestly, I forgot to think about it myself. Sometimes I get confused by all the plugins I use... :)